# Efficiently change hour of date column to value of another dataframe column R

Tags: r, performance, lubridate, tibble

Currently working to clean up a subset of data that's close to 15M rows. Eventually will be working with full data set closer to 120M rows.

Part of my data is dates in hourly increments, split among two columns. One column has the date (1/1/2020) format, another column has the hour corresponding to that date in integer form.

I have successfully accomplished my goal with the following code:

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(date = rep(c(mdy("1/1/2020")), each = 5), hour = 1:5)

hour(df$date) <- df$hour
```

To run this on the full 15M rows takes 120s on my (quite powerful) machine. I don't usually work with datasets this large, it seems to slow to me, but I am an armchair coder at best.

**Is that a reasonable time frame to accomplish my goal? If not, is there another function or more efficient way to accomplish the same result?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to `paste` the 'hour' into the 'date' column and reconvert to `Datetime` class with `ymd_h`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   mutate(date = ymd_h(str_c(date, hour, sep=' ')))
```

Comment: 2s. Much faster, thank you. Obviously I could wait the two minutes and move on, but trying to learn. I'm familiar with CS fundamentals but that's about it. Is there an ELI5 why mutate is so much faster?

Comment: @ghw29 it is not the mutate.  It is just that you in your assignment `hour(df$date) <-` it is creating a new entry 'hour in a 'Date' class.  Instead pasteing and converting to Datetime is much efficient